# Multiple count(*) with left join in one shot

Tags: sql, count, left-join, mariadb

I have 2 tables like this:

Table users:

```
   +--------------------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
   | Field                    | Type            | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
   +--------------------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
   | user_id                  | int(8) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
   | user_email               | varchar(40)     | NO   | UNI |         |                |
   | user_login               | varchar(30)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
   | user_password            | varchar(40)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
   | user_firstname           | varchar(30)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
   | user_lastname            | varchar(50)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
   +--------------------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Table users_oauth to link users with oauth, if there is no oauth entry for a user, the user has created an account with an email/password:

```
   +----------------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
   | Field                | Type            | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
   +----------------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
   | oauth_id             | int(8) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
   | oauth_user_id        | int(8) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
   | oauth_google_id      | varchar(30)     | YES  | UNI | NULL    |                |
   | oauth_facebook_id    | varchar(30)     | YES  | UNI | NULL    |                |
   | oauth_windowslive_id | varchar(30)     | YES  | UNI | NULL    |                |
   +----------------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

For a count between two dates, to know how many new users I do the following for facebook oauth:

```
SELECT date_format(`user_date_accountcreated`, "%Y-%m-%d") AS  date, COUNT(*) AS total FROM users 
LEFT JOIN users_oauth ON users_oauth.oauth_user_id = users.user_id 
WHERE (user_date_accountcreated BETWEEN '2016-10-01 00:00:00' AND '2016-10-15 23:59:59') AND oauth_facebook_id IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY year(user_date_accountcreated), month(user_date_accountcreated), day(user_date_accountcreated)
```

And another request for new users with google oauth, the only difference is `oauth_google_id IS NOT NULL` instead of `oauth_facebook_id IS NOT NULL`:

```
SELECT date_format(`user_date_accountcreated`, "%Y-%m-%d") AS  date, COUNT(*) AS total FROM users 
LEFT JOIN users_oauth ON users_oauth.oauth_user_id = users.user_id 
WHERE (user_date_accountcreated BETWEEN '2016-10-01 00:00:00' AND '2016-10-15 23:59:59') AND oauth_google_id IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY year(user_date_accountcreated), month(user_date_accountcreated), day(user_date_accountcreated)
```

And the last one for windows live oauth:

```
SELECT date_format(`user_date_accountcreated`, "%Y-%m-%d") AS  date, COUNT(*) AS total FROM users 
LEFT JOIN users_oauth ON users_oauth.oauth_user_id = users.user_id 
WHERE (user_date_accountcreated BETWEEN '2016-10-01 00:00:00' AND '2016-10-15 23:59:59') AND oauth_windowslive_id IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY year(user_date_accountcreated), month(user_date_accountcreated), day(user_date_accountcreated)
```

Is there any way to merge with 3 requests in only one with `COUNT(*) AS total_facebook`, `COUNT(*) AS total_google`, `COUNT(*) AS total_windowslive` ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by moving the `where` conditions to the `count`. This is called conditional aggregation.

Also when you`left join` and use a `where` condition, it is converted to an inner join. To avoid it move the date condition on to the `left join`.

```
SELECT 
date_format(`user_date_accountcreated`, "%Y-%m-%d") AS `date`, 
COUNT(case when oauth_facebook_id IS NOT NULL then 1 end ) AS total_facebook,
COUNT(case when oauth_google_id IS NOT NULL then 1 end) AS total_google,
COUNT(case when oauth_windowslive_id IS NOT NULL then 1 end) AS total_windowslive
FROM users 
LEFT JOIN users_oauth ON users_oauth.oauth_user_id = users.user_id 
AND user_date_accountcreated BETWEEN '2016-10-01 00:00:00' AND '2016-10-15 23:59:59'
GROUP BY date_format(`user_date_accountcreated`, "%Y-%m-%d")
--year(user_date_accountcreated), month(user_date_accountcreated), day(user_date_accountcreated)
```

Comment: I have only some 0 as result and strange but it goes until the 2014-01-25

Comment: I had to replace AND to WHERE, it works fine thanks @vkp

Comment: if you use `where` and a `left join` it is as good as doing an inner join.

Comment: Yes right, I did a test with a `INNER JOIN ` and it worked as well. :)